# Xcode error when compiling to phone: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

When I try and compile my project to my actual iPhone I get this error:

> ld: -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting
>   ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

However, when I compile to the built in simulator there are no errors... I have tried some suggestions online such as disabling bitcode, setting Build Active Architecture Only to No but no luck...

Comment: May be after changing the bitcode status you should clean the project and try to run this is the real device.

Comment: Already tried cleaning the project as well